# Rigging: Bones move in wrong direction

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I followed the tutorial from CG Geek (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBYb1YmaOMY) and added all bones. I added the inverse kinematics bone constraint to the lower leg and added the controller bone. When I move the controller bone the leg bends sideways to the x coordinate. When I set the pole angle to 90 degrees it works fine but the foot is pointing to the wrong direction.
Foot pointing forwards:

[image: Foot pointing forwards]

Leg bending forwards:

[image: Leg bending forwards]

Thanks for helping.

Edit: Here is the blender file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/uhkki052u9es30e/Human.blend/file

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I added it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IK *Pole Angle* should be 180°. Also in *Edit* mode pull the knee a bit forwards in order to bend the leg (see picture). And shouldn't you parent the foot to the controller?

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It works now. But in the tutorial the foot wasn't parented to the controller.

Comment: yes you can choose another way